# Unable to redirect bash output to variable file name

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable

I am trying to redirect the bash output to a variable file name. Here is my script looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat servers`
do
if [ "$i" = "198.162.1.3" ];
then
var="apple"
fi
ssh test@$i "uname -n"
done > /tempout/uname_${var}.txt
```

I am getting the filename as /tempout/uname_.txt

Expected filename should be uname_apple.txt

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: @glennjackman What makes you think "servers" is a file of lines/records and not just whitespace separated IP addresses?

Comment: Even if it is, the `for i in $(cat file)` is wrong. The shell will not only do word splitting (which is the desired effect), it also does filename expansion. `set -f` is missing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `var` variable in your code is used before the loop starts to create the output file.

If you want to output the result of the `ssh` command to a file whose name you construct from `$var`, then do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r server; do
    if [ "$server" = "198.162.1.3" ]; then
        var='apple'
    else
        var='unknown'
    fi

    ssh -n "test@$server" 'uname -n' >"/tempout/uname_$var.txt"
done <servers
```

Here, I've also changed the loop so that it reads the input file line by line (ignoring leading and trailing whitespace on each line), and I've made `var` get the value `unknown` if the `if` statement does not take the "true" branch.

Also, you need `-n` for `ssh`. Otherwise, `ssh` would consume all the available input (here redirected from the `servers` file).

Another change that could be made is to use `case ... esac` rather than an `if` statement, especially if the number of IP addresses that you test for is more than a couple:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r server; do
    case $server in
        198.162.1.3) var=apple ;;
        198.162.1.5) var=cottage ;;
        198.162.1.7) var=bumblebee ;;
        *) var=unknown
    esac

    ssh -n "test@$server" 'uname -n' >"/tempout/uname_$var.txt"
done <servers
```

Comment: the input redirection to read is more elegant, but the loop behaves fundamentally different like that. if IP appears in a line together with other words it won't be recognized.

Comment: @Sam Yes, the new code expects `servers` to be a list of IP addresses, one per line.

Comment: _one per line_, with leading and trailing spaces or tabs removed (assuming the default value of `$IFS`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: I’m trying to understand your comment. It looks like it’s intended as a correction to [Kusalananda’s comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/467491/80216#comment851854_467493), and, IMHO, it doesn’t work as such. Arguably, Kusalananda’s comment should say “the new code expects `servers` to be a list of IP addresses, one per line, ***with optional leading and trailing spaces or tabs** (which will be removed / ignored)*.”

Comment: @Kusalananda:  Do you just always use ```read```’s ```-r``` option unless you have a reason to leave it out?  If so, I suppose that’s a reasonable practice.  Otherwise, I don’t see a need for it here; there is no *a priori* reason to expect a list of servers to contain backslashes.

Comment: @G-Man It's true that there may be no real reason to use `-r` here.

Comment: @G-Man Stéphanes' comment was a clarification to my text, not a correction (that's how I read it at least). He is absolutely correct, but just like with your comment regarding my use of `read -r`, it's unlikely to make a big difference here as IP addresses rarely include leading or trailing whitespace.  I _would_ matter if `IFS` has a non-default value (like a collection of digits), in which case using `IFS=` (no value) in front of `read` becomes important.